# Where'd my Xcode symbols go?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, symbols

Some time in the last hour some pretty weird things have been happening with Xcode. There are, apparently, no symbols in my project at all.

[image: Interesting...]
Quite the project...

Even alt-clicking on SDK elements (which would typically bring up the quick help side bar) does nothing. Documentation is downloaded.

[image: A world without NSLogs...]A world without NSLogs...

Command clicking a class or other object typically sends you to the item's declaration. No such luck for me! All function, classes, methods and pretty much everything but keywords, strings and chars are showing up as plain text within Xcode.

[image: Plain text looks so boring. How did people write code before IDEs?!]I <3 My IDE Syntax Formatting

Help me get my symbols back!
I've cleaned, I've rebuilt, I've restarted and made sure all the Dwarf settings were right and what not.

[image: Help find the lost symbols!]Help find the lost symbols!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: @joze No, however I tried in it both the beta and stable versions. No cigar.

Comment: If I where you I would reinstall it. It seems to me (even if I have never encountered this problem) that some configuration setting got changed and if it is related with the IDE the best way is reinstalling it instead of investing time finding the specific solution.

Comment: @Joze just tried it on a virtual machine. Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experienced your exact issue, but if this happened to me the first thing I'd try is to delete the project derived data using the button in the `Organizer`, `Projects` tab, and then restart XCode immediately.  Hope this helps.